# I have redesigned a website and my blog page has different permalinks

Tags: seo, permalinks

im a new website developer and i dont have much experience with this subject.

I made a new website for a customer using wordpress ( also the previous uses wordpress)

My question is , in the old website the links are like this

```
Page -> www.[mywebsite].com/page-name
Portfolio -> www.[mywebsite].com/portfolio/portfolio-page
blog-> www.[mywebsite].com/blog-page
```

which was wrong because the blog pages are not made with posts but with wordpress pages thats why the blog page doesnt have a /category/ before its name.

in the new website the blog posts are made with posts instead with the category

My issue is, that right now if i set the permalinks it shows like this

```
Page -> www.[mywebsite].com/page-name
Portfolio -> www.[mywebsite].com/portfolio/portfolio-page
blog-> www.[mywebsite].com/**blog-category**/blog-page
```

and if i make the permalinks as simple it shows like this

```
Page -> www.[mywebsite].com/page-name
Portfolio -> www.[mywebsite].com/portfolio-page
blog-> www.[mywebsite].com/blog-page
```

so my question is, is there any way that i make the permalinks of the blog to NOT show the category of the posts but show the category of the portfolio ?

if this has been answered before im very sorry. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So you want your blog post links to read: www.[mywebsite].com/portfolio/blog-page ?

Comment: No , i want my portfolio links to keep their parent url but my posts to show without a parent url or uncategorized

portfolios -> www.[mywebsite.com]./portfolio-category/portfolio-page
blog -> www.[mywebsite].com/post-page

Comment: How are you registering the Portfolio post type? It sounds like you need to set permalinks to not use the category, which will fix the blog posts, and then make sure you register the Portfolio CPT to use `/portfolio/` in the URLs.